# Xamarin Visual State Manager Cannot Resolve Property Type on nested element

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and I wanted to try changing the radio button's appearance. But with my current codes I get the error `Cannot resolve property type "TextColor" on type "Grid"`.

Here are my codes:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
            <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkBorderTop"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="{x:StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkBorderBot"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="{x:StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="check"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="{x:StaticResource PrimaryShade}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkIcon"
                                            Property="TextColor"
                                            Value="{x:StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkBorderTop"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkBorderBot"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="check"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkIcon"
                                            Property="TextColor"
                                            Value="Black"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <BoxView x:Name="checkBorderTop" 
                         Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Frame x:Name="check" 
                       BorderColor="Transparent"
                       Margin="0"
                       Padding="20, 10"
                       Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label x:Name="checkIcon" 
                               Text="{x:Static icon:FontAwesomeIcons.Paw}"
                               FontFamily="IconSolid"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               FontSize="20"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
                <BoxView x:Name="checkBorderBot"
                         Grid.Row="2"
                         Margin="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

Here is my expected output:
[image]

The code works well on changing the background color and border. But when I add

```
<Setter TargetName="checkIcon"
        Property="TextColor"
        Value="{x:StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
```

the error shows. I can't manage to change the Paw icon color when checked and unchecked.
I think its on the hierarchy between the parent and child elements since the label is on the most inner child, idk.

Need help from those who know the answer :(

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's often necessary to share the same Visual State Manager markup among two or more views.

That is to say you can use `Style` for the `Grid` elements in the View page:

```
           <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="RowSpacing" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkBorderTop"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="{x:StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkBorderBot"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="{x:StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="check"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="{x:StaticResource PrimaryShade}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkIcon"
                                            Property="TextColor"
                                            Value="{x:StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkBorderTop"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkBorderBot"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="check"
                                            Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="checkIcon"
                                            Property="TextColor"
                                            Value="Black"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Wish it could be helpful to you.

Comment: For more details, you can refer to this doc: [Visual State Manager markup in a style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager#visual-state-manager-markup-in-a-style) by official.